# "We don't install..." or "We didn't install..."?

Tags: past-simple, present-simple

I'm confused about whether I should choose present simple or past simple in this context:

> **X**: Why can't I find the Wi-Fi network?
>
> **Y**: Err... We __(install) Wi-Fi in our home.

Note that **Y** has no intention to install Wi-Fi in the future.

Comment: Who is saying this? Is it a conversation betwee a regular owner of a single home and a visitor, or is it e.g. between someone who builds houses for a living and a prospective purchaser?

Comment: @CaiusJard a single home and a visitor.

Comment: Just my two cents as a non-native english speaker: the "in our home" part makes me think that "we don't have/we don't use" make much more sense than "we don't install/we didn't install".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I (British English speaker) would always use the "present perfect": *We haven't installed*.

I believe many AmE speakers could say *We didn't install* (but I'm not an expert).

If you want to indicate that you have no intention of installing WiFi, then either *We're not installing* or *We won't install*.

*We don't install* doesn't make much sense, unless you mean that you never install it in any house you live in.

Comment: "We don't install doesn't make much sense, unless you mean that you never install it in any house you live in." I think it makes sense. It has connotations of the person in question having moral or ethical objections to installing wifi - like maybe an Amish person that objects to modern technology.

Comment: "Haven't" implies "yet". As in "We haven't installed WI-Fi in our home yet. We might do so at a later date". "Don't" implies that we have not, and will never, for XX reason. Possibly a cultural taboo, a religious restriction, a court order, or some similar binding prohibition. "We don't install wi-fi here" is a similar statement to "We don't date our sisters here"

Comment: I wasn't aware of any divide on this issue between American and British speakers generally.  As a Michigan native I have no preference between the two phrases you give.  They both sound perfectly natural to me.  I mean, I do see it come up under the 'Equivalent idioms' section on the Wikipedia page for differences, but I think it is one of the weakest differences.  Well, I guess it says that for AmE "(the British forms are also acceptable)."  Perhaps only the Brits get persnickety over this one, whereas anyone that says "in future" within my earshot shall be sent 1000 bargepoles distant.

Comment: The BrE/AmE thing is so tiring. Not everyone in the States says did for haven't. What people don't seem to understand about this is that there are millions more people in the US than in the UK, so it can sound like this truism is true but it isn't. People who would say: We didn't install it yet, have their counterparts in the UK.

Comment: @Lambie While I agree that none of these rules are absolute, but: in the UK, both "we didn't install it" and "we haven't installed it" are fine (but subtly different): "we haven't installed it yet" is also fine, but "we didn't install it yet"  sounds very unidiomatic.

Comment: @MichaelKay You misunderstood my comment. yet is normally used with the present perfect, in the US, too. It is not unidiomatic. It's a class (education, level of language) thing. And there are many, many class things in the UK, too.

Comment: @Lambie UK rules also apply (with some variation) to many other English-speaking countries, e.g. Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, India, South Africa, etc.  (Canada is generally closer to US usage).  So the numbers aren't quite as heavily biased towards AmE as you might think just based on only US and UK.  In this case, however, I think *"didn't install"* and *"haven't installed"* would both sound equally acceptable to any English-speaker.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman First, there is no rule. There is usage. That said, of course both "didn't install" and "haven't installed" are idiomatic across all varieties of English. The issue here is: **didn't install it yet** versus "haven't installed it yet". The standard way to use **yet** is with the present perfect and not with the simple past. But one hears everyone saying that only AmE speakers "use yet with simple past". And I don't buy it. And I think people say that because you hear AmE speakers use that in the media, movies, etc. That is where they myth has arisen.

Answer (score 38):

I wouldn't even use the verb "install":

> We don't have Wi-Fi in our home.

Comment: I didn't think of that before! Thank you. By the way, between this sentence and I haven't installed Wi-Fi in our home, which one is more likely to say, in your opinion?

Comment: @user516076 I think "We don't have Wi-Fi" would be more common in everyday colloquial speech. To my ear, "We haven't installed/didn't install Wi-Fi" puts undue emphasis on the installation process itself, suggesting that the home doesn't have WiFi because the owners did not or could not complete the installation. For example, "We haven't installed WiFi because it would be too much work", or "We haven't installed WiFi yet, but the cable company is coming to give us a quote next week."

Comment: This is correct though it doesn't answer the OP's question

Comment: BTW – no hate, just a statement + I upvoted

Comment: @user516076 "Install" isn't really a word that we use with WiFi, anyway. If you wanted to say that you didn't have WiFi yet but were going to in the future then you would say, "We haven't _set up_ the WiFi yet." (I'm really not sure why, but for physical objects installed seems to be for more serious connections, like installing central heating, whereas set up would be for minor ones, like a book case or the WiFi.)

Comment: Or, "We don't use wifi".

Comment: Ah, but @stan, I don't use WiFi for my desktop, but I do on my phone...

Comment: @NobodyNada - that could also imply that there's no signal, therefore no point.

Comment: @texasboy This is a frame challenge, and as such it does answer the question. It could perhaps be more explicit by saying "You should choose neither of these" but I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: Ah, but @FreeMan what you personally use on which device isn't the point, is it? If you use Wi-Fi on your phone, you have Wi-Fi…

Answer (score 2):

My first choice would be, “We **haven’t installed** wi-fi.” “We **didn’t install** wi-fi,” or “We **don’t have** wi-fi,” would also work. (Installing Wi-Fi in the past would be necessary to have it in the present.)

In this context, “We don’t install wi-fi in our offices,” or, “The Amish don’t install electronics in their homes,” would mean they never do.

Comment: +1 for "We don’t have wi-fi"

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't choose the simple past tense, because that usually implies that the event happened at a particular time. The present perfect is usually a better option when the time is unspecified: "We haven't installed wi-fi in our home." (Because Colin Fine brought up the issue, I'll mention that I'm a native American English speaker.) I agree with CF that the present tense doesn't seem suitable here. If you want to make clear that you have no intention of installing wi-fi in the future, then you can say so explicitly, e.g.: "We haven't installed wi-fi in our home and do not intend to do so."

Comment: It could be used the other way as well, e.g. *"We haven't installed wi-fi in our home, but we intend to in the future"*.  Compare that to *"We didn't install wi-fi in our new home, but we did in our previous home."*  This shows that it was a deliberate choice to not install it, rather than just being something you haven't gotten around to yet.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi isn't something that you "install". It is not a physical object or software.

Options (for an on going scenario):

- We don't enable the Wi-Fi (If you have a router, but disabled the Wi-Fi and only use network cables.)
- We don't have a router, we just use mobile data.
- We don't have a network(/an Internet) connection for the house, we ...
- etc.

Comment: It's common in my country to use a sentence that doesn't literally mean what it actually means. I translated the sentence from my native language into English in my mind, I should apologize bcz I couldn't determine whether it's colloquial or not.

Comment: To me, it's quite natural to *hear*, "We haven't installed WiFi" to mean something like, "We haven't installed WiFi-capable routers" or "We haven't enabled WiFi on our routers", or even, "We don't have WiFi (and don't really know how to do that anyway). I wouldn't say it myself because I understand the nuts-and-bolts of how WiFi works, but it's still natural enough English.

Comment: @gotube just because it sounds right doesn't make it right. I am a native English speaker and I also understand all the technical aspects. There are a lot of common phrases that are incorrect technically, I wouldn't recommend incorrect language usage, even if it is common.

Comment: "just because it sounds right doesn't make it right" It literally does make it right. Language is constructed by language users. English grammar rules aren't handed down either from heaven or the government.

Comment: This is actually an example of metonymy. "My house has  wifi" does not mean "The abstract concept of wifi is contained within my house." It means "The hardware and services needed to provide wifi service are available at my house." Using the word "wifi" to stand for the services and equipment that provide wifi is easily understood and not wrong. It's no different than saying "the news media" when what you really mean is "the employees and publishing companies who provide news products via certain media." English is full of such shorthands and abbreviations.

Comment: @barbecue "has" makes sense, "install" does not.

Comment: @Danny it only makes sense through convention and habit, there's no internally consistent set of rules by which one makes sense and the other does not.

Comment: Since you seem to be concerned about the "have" versus "install" thing, the same concept is easily expressed. "We haven't installed wifi" does not mean "We haven't installed an abstract concept of wifi communications," it means "We haven't installed the physical things required to provide the service known as wifi." As I said before, it's metonymy, using a word descriptive of the thing to stand for the thing. It's perfectly grammatical, and not wrong at all. I only brought this up because you said "Wi-Fi isn't something that you "install". It is not a physical object or software."

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you should expect to hear simply "We don't have Wi-Fi."

If the choice is really limited to the terms of the Question, with no other clues to the context, then "We didn't install…" would be much more likely.

Even then, "We didn't install…" as a simple statement of what happened might well be explained by the fact that "We don't install…" as a general principle. What reason there might be for that is too far from the main Question to matter here, but *any* reason would make both versions correct.

In the context you gave, the past simple "We didn't…" would be the correct choice… but only in strict terms of school-book grammar. There is prolly much less than a 5% chance of any native English speaker using that wording.

You might (just) come across "We didn't install Wi-Fi…" but "*… in our home*…" is so unlikely as not to be worth thinking about.

Note that Y having no intention to install Wi-Fi in the future makes the whole idea too complex to consider in any short space.